# How to play a Game with Commands Environment?

Tags: command-line, java, desktop-environment, minecraft, tinycore

So now i have a very old laptops. Only having 2 GB ram. And i really wanted to play Minecraft (Java). But whenever i play it, its always dropping to 20-30 fps somehow (In Bodhi, and Q4OS Trinity. And i think the DE can affect this. So i have an idea to play Minecraft without installing any DE or application. Just the core, drivers, and minecraft, nothing else.

But idk is it possible or not. Or i should install DE to provide a GUI? The game it self use .jar so i think its possible. But idk, maybe someone could explain me?

Thank you very much for answering :)

Comment: Minecraft is notorious for eating up lots of memory (and so is Java). 2GB really is at the bottom end - I'd heavily suggest upgrading. You can not have graphical programs without atleast an `X` server.

Comment: Yes and i very wnted to upgrade. The problem is i having Laptops not a PC. So i think i can only upgrade ram. I knew that 2GB ram is bottom end. But i dont have money to buy a new laptop. Is there anything that can help somehow? (Also i found the FPS is better in windows than in linux)

Comment: Does Windows manage to load into 2GB? The usual minimum for Windows is 4GB. You could check that Linux has a decent swap partition, ideally on a fast drive, but you really need more RAM.